# What are the downsides of using cfr-lm instead of lmodern?

Tags: lmodern, cfr-lm

As I understand it, the package `cfr-lm` can access a lot more features of the Latin Modern fonts than `lmodern`.  However, `cfr-lm` makes use of virtual fonts.  How do these virtual fonts interact with the regular Latin Modern fonts themselves, and what are the downsides of using `cfr-lm` instead of `lmodern`?

Comment: Virtual fonts are quite normal,  lots of fonts use them.

Comment: Some of the new commands it enables might clash with something?

Comment: According to the `cfr-lm` documentation only `EC/T1` and `TS1` encodings are supported.